# Non-blocking call to ofstream::open?

Tags: c++, io, nonblocking, ofstream

I have a C++ program which opens files in /tmp (on a *nix system) and reads their contents.

To do this, I am using:

```
ofstream dest;
dest.open(abs_path.c_str(), ios::app);
```

where abs_path is a string containing the absolute path to the file.

The problem is that some *nix programs create named pipes as files in /tmp. For example,

```
 /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-23732-by-myusername-on-???
```

Is a pipe created by a debugging utility I am using.

In the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/)  for ofstream, the open method it says that the method sets an error bit when opening the file fails. However, in my tests it instead hangs trying to open the file (which is actually a pipe) indefinitely. I assume this is because the file is locked by another program (probably the debugger).

So, **how can I force ofstream::open to block for a finite amount of time, or not at all?** It's easy enough to clean up gracefully if it fails, but it needs to actually fail first..

Comment: If I recall correctly, the pipe must be opened on both ends before the `open` call succeeds. Also, a named pipe is outside the scope of the C++ standard, so the `ofstream` documentation probably doesn't consider it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't.  `filebuf::open` (called by
`ofstream`) basically delegates to the OS, and supposed that the OS will
do the right thing.  And the interface it supports is very, very
limited; many important options to `open` (`O_SYNC`, `O_NONBLOCK`, etc)
aren't mapped, and thus can't be used.  The only solutions I've found to
this is either to use `std::ostringstream`, then write the string to the
file using system level calls, or to write my own `streambuf`, which
does what I want (much simpler than it sounds, since you typically only
need part of what `filebuf` offers—you often don't need
bidirectionality, seeking or code translation).

Neither of these solutions are portable, of course.

Finally, I'm not sure why you're writing into `/tmp`.  By convention,
anything you put into `/tmp` should contain the process id.  And for
security reasons, I'd always create a subdirectory, with the process id
in its name, and with very limited access rights, and create any
temporary files in it.

Comment: Is 23732 not the PID? Creating a subdirectory isn't essential IMO, it depends how much engineering you want to do to defend your debugger from being watched by other users of the system as it creates files. You might have to take this one up with the authors of valgrind.

Comment: And also -- if you're using `/tmp`, it might not be a big leap to assume Posix and use `open` instead of `fopen` in order to use the extra flags.

Comment: Very helpful. Perhaps this should be it's own question, but is there a good reason why these options are not mapped? Seems like they exist in some form on most (all?) systems, and ought to be part of the standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop 23732 is presumably the pid of the debugger which created this named pipe.  If so, it's not his pid (although with network mounts...).  With regards to creating the subdirectory, it depends, but it's a good precautionary measure, since it allows you to use `ofstream` to create files within it without any real risk.

Comment: @SteveJessop I did sort of suppose that he was using some sort of Unix; the options to `open` (and in fact `open` itself) have different names in Windows.  (And where did you see any reference to `fopen`, either in his code or mine?)

Comment: @JohnDoucette Probably historical.  C++ really doesn't go beyond C, and when C was being defined, these options weren't available.  I'm not sure to what degree `O_NONBLOCK` is important, but you can't write any transactional software without `O_SYNC`.  (FWIW, Java supports it.)

Comment: @James: `basic_filebuf::open` then, the point is that the C++ standard only assumes what the C standard assumes in terms of OS capability. In my brain the difference between what you need and what's "portable" (in the sense of portable that I presume you meant when you said none of your solutions was portable) is characterized as the difference between `open` and `fopen`. All I meant is that Posix appears to be as portable as it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as non-blocking input defined by the C++ language. (There is a method std::streambuf::in_avail(), but still it can't help you)

You can consider using C method

```
int file_descr = open( "pipe_addr", O_RDONLY |O_NONBLOCK);
```

instead of std::ofstream